# Paper on returns from perfect market timing?

Tags: backtesting, prediction, market

I'm looking for a (free) paper I read which showed that even a "perfect" market timing strategy wasn't very good compared to buy-and-hold. There were some restrictions to the timing, something like: you buy at the lowest point between all time highs and sell at each all time high...and they concluded that it still wasn't a very good strategy because you spend a lot of time not invested.

Anyone know this study?

Comment: Was my answer helpful? In that case, it is good practice here to upvote and accept the answer. Thank you, best h

Answer (score 3):

In the long term, you will outperform buy & hold with a market timing accuracy of > 65%.

See these papers for more:

- Bauer, R.; Dahlquist, J.: „Market Timing and Roulette Wheels“, Financial Analysts Journal, 01 Jan 2001, Volume 57, Issue 1, https://doi.org/10.2469/faj.v57.n1.2417.
- Sharpe, W.: “Likely Gains from Market Timing”, Financial Analysts Journal, 31. December 2018, https://doi.org/10.2469/faj.v31.n2.60.

Comment: Did you mean "Will *not* outperform..."?

Comment: @RobertHarvey No, I mean it the way it says there. The better your market timing abilities the better your chance of outperforming buy&hold obviously.

Comment: Your choices for proofs are not exactly ringing endorsements.  The first one says that portfolio managers could have gotten 59 percent accuracty *with random choices.*  The second one is behind a paywall.

Comment: @RobertHarvey: This statement does not contradict the other statement. Concerning the paper: my colleague Prof. Dr. Google might help you find a free version ;-)

Comment: Are you simply asserting that if you get timing accuracy of >65%, you will outperform buy and hold?  If that is even true (and I doubt that it is), what is your proposal for obtaining greater than 65% timing accuracy?  Because you won't get it with the first paper's strategy.

Comment: It has been quite some time since I worked on those problems (including running many simulations myself)... bear with me, I would have to check back.

Comment: Some of this is subjective:  Buy and Hold means no timing ever.  Would you be happy to be in the market for 1 day and have a 1000% percent return, and out of the market the rest of the time?